# How to extract nested elements in JSON response using JSON extractor in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

I would like to extract an element based on a condition inside a nested JSON response.  Using the widely searched example below, I would like to extract the storeid of all books authored by "Foo Bar":

```
{
    "store": {
        "storeId": 1
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": [
                      {
                       "Nigel Rees",
                       "Foo Bar"
                      }
                ],
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": [
                      { 
                       "Evelyn Waugh"
                      }
                ],
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I have tried using expressions like:
$.store[?(@..author=='Foo Bar')].storeId

I have also tried to see if there are any store returned at all using:
$.store[*].book[?(@.author=='Foo Bar')]

But no result returned...  Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you produced [is not a valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) so you won't be able to use JSON Extractor on it.

If you amend [this good example](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples) which you cannot even properly copy and paste to include your `storeId`:

```
{
  "store": {
    "storeId": 1,
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

You will be able to extract the `storeId` where one of the authors is `Nigel Rees` using the following expression:

```
$.store[?(@.book[?(@.author=="Nigel Rees")])].storeId
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Json Path Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri but I think that will only extract all storeId with book and doesn't look into the nested author == "Nigel Rees"...